# Length unchanged after using delete

Tags: javascript

I have a function which deletes from an object array but when i check it's `.length` its the same..

This is what i have:

```
console.log(data.length);

delete(data[i]);

console.log(data.length);
console.log(data);
```

My outputs end up like this:

```
3
3
[object Array]
```

I have attatched the image of the object array below, you see only 2 entires but the length is still 3.

[image]

The initial data im testing with is this:

```
[
  {"equip":"0","name":"Test","id":"10"},
  {"equip":"0","name":"Test","id":"4"},
  {"equip":"0","name":"Test","id":"5"}
]
```

You can see my browser has deleted one from the object array.. so why does it still count 3, and how do I fix that so it counts correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete operator deletes a property from an object. In your case, property `i`. Properties in an array are actually indexes `0` through `array.length - 1`. Use splice instead:

```
data.splice(i, 1);
```

To find out the number of properties in an object, use `Object.keys`:

`Object.keys(data).length` will result in 2

Comment: Does that mean i don't need to use `delete` at all then ?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to if you were using the array methods: `splice`, `push`, `pop`, etc. These methods adjust the `length` of the array accordingly

Answer (score 1):

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected.
>   This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is used to remove element from object for array use `splice`

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```